# Setting Transparency in .IMG format

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

Is there a way for QGIS make just the black value (255,255,255) on an **.IMG format file** transparency. Right now their transparent option makes the whole image transparent.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has the option to set transparency based on a number of factors no matter the file format you use.

All can be set from the *Transparency* tab in the raster layer *Properties*. Just set 100% transparency for red=255, green=255 and blue=255.

[image: QGIS transparency]